# Открытие приложения через fragment(android)

Tags: android, android-studio

Есть фрагмент-страница, на ней нужно указать несколько ссылок на страницы вк при нажатии которых открывается приложение вк.
Проблема в том, что не могу сообразить, что прописать в fragment и в xml файл

Можете ли подсказать гайд/видео/примерный код на который можно ориентироваться и написать самостоятельно/скопировать?
Фрагмент вообще чистый.

```html
package com.example.glavnaya;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;



public class blagodarnosty extends Fragment {


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //returning our layout file
        //change R.layout.yourlayoutfilename for each of your fragments
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.blagodarnosty, container, false);


    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Добавляем textView в разметку
2. вешаем в коде на textView листенер https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660257/how-to-set-listener-for-textview
3. в листенере открываем сайт https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application